# GNU Privacy Guard - passwords for symmetric encryption and signature

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I am working a .NET library for encryption to put a wrapper around GPG and am stuck on one combination that I have encountered. I am trying to use symmetric encryption (-c)  AND sign the result (-s) with my private key.  I need to accomplish this without a password window appearing.  I am able pass a single password using passphrase-fd without problem, but this requires two passwords - one for the encryption and one for the password.

Is this a realistic scenario?

Is there any way to do this without a password window popping up?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using one of native .NET implementations of OpenPGP rather than writing wrappers?

Comment: I need to support GPG explicitly as it is open source and what other proven systems are using as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

gpg -c ... -u [signing user id or key hex id] ...

Comment: This only passes a key, not the passphrase for the key or the passphrase for the text to be encrypted.